# Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, datatables

I am using MVC(ASP.Net + C#) based application. I have used Jquery DataTable to display records. Now issue is that for some records its working good and for some records it's giving me error like "Timeout expired" at front end side.

I am using Entity Framework & Stored Procedure to fetch records. For some values It's giving me Timeout Error. If I directly executed this Sp with those require parameters (in which it's giving me Timeout Error) then it's working fine(but taking bit time around 11 seconds in SQL Server.). I just getting Timeout error frond end side.

I am getting below error.

> {"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding."} {"The wait operation
>   timed out"}

I have tried added in web.config

1. Connection Lifetime=120;
2. Min Pool Size=120;
3. Connection Timeout=300;
4. Max Pool Size=1000;Pooling=true;
5. `<httpRuntime  executionTimeout="180" maxRequestLength="2000000000"  />`

But didn't workout.

***My Web.Config as below.***

```
<add name="TestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Test2.csdl|res://*/Test2.ssdl|res://*/Test2.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Test2;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;Connection Lifetime=120;Min Pool Size=120;Connection Timeout=300;Max Pool Size=1000;Pooling=true;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Please help.

Thanks
-Nimesh

Comment: I think you need to set/increase the `command timeout` where you call the stored procedure on the data context. The http runtime is for when the request times out against the IIS, and connection timeout is for creating connection. (also - based on your mention, it might be the stored procedure also suffers from parameter sniffing issues and/or should be optimized)

Comment: In my experience, you should always first try to fix timeouts by - fixing them. That is, make sure that the sproc finishes in time, e.g. by adding paging parameters. If that doesn't help (not: if you don't want to try) then as a last resort increase command/transaction timeout. But expect other timeouts to kick in too (IIS, Machine settings, ...). In fact, if you can't reduce the execution time, you should probably look for an asynchronous protocol like web sockets.

Comment: FYI, I am generated complex type of that Sps and generate types.

Answer (score 2):

SQL server creates an execution plan for stored procedures to optimize the performance for further executions (parameter sniffing). When you execute this stored procedure on `SSMS`, it works fine but when you try to execute the same stored procedure from your ASP.NET MVC application, you'd face the timeout issue.
You can fix this by re-creating/altering your stored procedure **`WITH RECOMPILE`** option (after your parameters). I faced this issue today; altered my stored procedure **`WITH RECOMPILE`** option and it worked like a charm. For more details, read about **`Parameter Sniffing`**.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved issue by increasing CommandTimeout To 120

```
Db.CommandTimeout = 120;
```